# Run a single case test with maven in parallel [BASH]

Tags: bash, maven, testing, parallel-processing

I need to run n times the same test case and count the number of times the test pass or fail. I wrote the following snippet of code:

```
CONCATNAME=$CLASSNAME”#”$METHODNAME
PASSTEST=0
FAILTEST=0
TOSEARCH="BUILD SUCCESS"
i=0
for i in $( seq 1 $NROUNDS )
do
    echo "exec command: mvn -Dtest="$CONCATNAME" test"
    message=$(mvn -Dtest=$CONCATNAME test)
    if echo "$message" | grep -q "$TOSEARCH"; then
        PASSTEST=$((PASSTEST+1))
    else 
        FAILTEST=$((FAILTEST+1))
    fi
done
```

but the execution takes several minutes to complete. Is it possible without modifying the POM.xml file to run the mvn -Dtest command in parallel?

Comment: Which unit test framework are you using? JUnit Jupiter  or JUnit 4?

Comment: JUnit 4 and I can not change version since my goal is to run a single test case n times without altering the repo

Comment: I strongly recommend to use an other approach, cause running the whole build process takes much time and it's waste of time See https://github.com/anderson-marques/concurrent-testing (Rules)... apart from that I don't understand what should the test prove? And what do you mean by `parallel` in the headline? You are not running tests in parallel?...

Comment: My goal is to run n times the same test case to see if it has the same behavior each time and I wanted to make it find a way to run them in parallel to decrease the execution time

Comment: As I already mentioned use a rule like mentioned above otherwise that will take too long and will waste a lot of time...apart from that I recommend to make a code review of the code and of the test to check if an issue could already found by a human...and of course check if this test is a unit test or an integration test?

Comment: I'll look at the rules mentioned, thank you.
But a hand inspection is not feasible as there are more than 1000 repos to be analyzed and some of them show "abnormal" behaviors after more than 1000 executions.

Comment: The issue here that you have written about a single test case... Sounds like an very challenging problem..I would focus on those which have failed and make a code review on tests...most of the times this shows already there are issues in the tests or more often within the code....BTW: Is there no CI solution running and showing the trend of tests failing over the time?

Comment: But my goal at the moment is to replicate through a large number of executions the intermittent failure of the test cases examined (see flaky test).
Subsequently, after having identified (and confirmed) them, I can move on to perform an analysis to understand the cause that generated the intermittent fail